# tabcmd facing issues while running and passing sub folders

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am using tabcmd command as below

```
tabcmd refreshextracts --workbook "Information scehma" --project "Insurance 1.0/STAGE" --server "https://tableaubi_prod_hchc.com/" --user "abc123"
```

its able to read the folder until "Insurance 1.0" but its not able to read sub folders.

Is there anything need to be modified in the command? I am trying for the first time using tabcmd

I am trying to run using windows cmd command prompt and testing this

> Error: Unable to find the project public class com.tableausoftware.domain.exceptions.NotFoundException